# Installation of openenebula

Tags: system-installation, java

To use the opennebula java api in an application is it necessary to install opennebula and its node in my guest machine( ubuntu 16.04)?

Comment: `opennebula-java, opennebula-node` etc. are available with `apt install`  https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial&searchon=names&keywords=opennebula

Comment: @KnudLarsen I need just the API for my application, so should i install the openenebula system or just use the jars ?